# What does regex' flag 'y' do?

Tags: javascript, regex, flags

MDN says:

> To perform a "sticky" search, that
>   matches starting at the current
>   position in the target string, use the
>   y flag.

I don't quite understand it.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Regular expression objects have a `lastIndex` property, which is used in different ways depending on the `g` ([global](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/global)) and `y` ([sticky](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/sticky)) flags. The `y` (sticky) flag tells the regular expression to look for a match at `lastIndex` and **only** at `lastIndex` (not earlier or later in the string).

Examples are worth 1024 words:

```js
var str =  "a0bc1";
// Indexes: 01234

var rexWithout = /\d/;
var rexWith    = /\d/y;

// Without:
rexWithout.lastIndex = 2;          // (This is a no-op, because the regex
                                   // doesn't have either g or y.)
console.log(rexWithout.exec(str)); // ["0"], found at index 1, because without
                                   // the g or y flag, the search is always from
                                   // index 0

// With, unsuccessful:
rexWith.lastIndex = 2;             // Says to *only* match at index 2.
console.log(rexWith.exec(str));    // => null, there's no match at index 2,
                                   // only earlier (index 1) or later (index 4)

// With, successful:
rexWith.lastIndex = 1;             // Says to *only* match at index 1.
console.log(rexWith.exec(str));    // => ["0"], there was a match at index 1.

// With, successful again:
rexWith.lastIndex = 4;             // Says to *only* match at index 4.
console.log(rexWith.exec(str));    // => ["1"], there was a match at index 4.
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

---

**Compatibility Note**:

Firefox's SpiderMonkey JavaScript engine has had the `y` flag for years, but it wasn't part of the specification until ES2015 (June 2015). Also, for quite a while Firefox had [a bug in the handling of the `y` flag](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=773687) with regard to the `^` assertion, but it was fixed somewhere between Firefox 43 (has the bug) and Firefox 47 (doesn't). Very old versions of Firefox (say, 3.6) did have `y` and didn't have the bug, so it was a regression that happened later (not defined behavior for the `y` flag), and then got fixed.