# Regex to match each subdomain of a URL

Tags: javascript, regex, subdomain

I'm trying to write a Regex that extracts the subdomain/domain parts of a URL as separate strings.

I've tried this:

`/^[^:]+:\/\/([^\.\/]+)(\.[^\.\/]+)+(?:\/|$)/`

It should work against these URLs:

`http;//www.mail.yahoo.co.uk/blah/blah`

`http;//test.test.again.mail.yahoo.com/blah/blah`

I want to break it into it's parts like so:

`["http://", "www", ".mail", ".yahoo", ".co", ".uk"]`

`["http://", "test", ".test", ".again", ".mail", ".yahoo", ".com"]`

Now I'm only able to capture them as:

`["http://", "www", ".uk"]`

`["http://", "test", ".com"]`

Anyone know how I can fix my regex?

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: It's just `regex.exec(url)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `/(http[s]?:\/\/|\w+(?=\.)|\.\w+)/g`. [Test it online](https://regex101.com/r/udm0R6/1)

Comment: Could you explain why use `/^[^:]+:\/\/([^\.\/]+)(\.[^\.\/]+)+(?:\/|$)/` to match `http://test.test.again.mail.yahoo.com/blah/blah` only have two groups. Does `()+` will not expand, only one group. If I want to have multi groups with same pattern, how to write it?

Comment: Let me try with a simple example. Consider a mobile number with digits `98997088567` and these 3 scenarios: `([9])` means match and return all occurrences of digit `9`, `([9]+)`means match and return all occurrences of consecutive `9`s, `([9])+`means all occurrences of consecutive `9`s but return only last matched group.

Comment: Thank you! I understand. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regex

```
(^\w+:\/\/)([^.]+)
```

to match the first part and then use

```
\.\w+
```

to match the second part

check the code snippet

```js
function getSubDomains(str){
    let result = str.match(/(^\w+:\/\/)([^.]+)/);
    result.splice(0, 1);
    result = result.concat(str.match(/\.\w+/g));
    console.log(result);
    return result;
}

getSubDomains('http://www.mail.yahoo.co.uk/blah/blah');
getSubDomains('http://test.test.again.mail.yahoo.com/blah/blah');
```

Answer (score 0):

How about chaining matches to start by use of [sticky flag `y`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4542304/what-does-regex-flag-y-do)

```js
var str = 'http://test.test.again.mail.yahoo.com/blah/blah';

var res = str.match(/^[a-z]+:\/\/|\.?[^/.\s]+/yig);

console.log(res);
```

- `^[a-z]+:\/\/` matches the protocol: start, one or more a-z, followed by colon and double slash.
- `|\.?[^/.\s]+` or optional dot followed by one or more chr [that are not](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) slash, dot, whitespace.

[See Regex101 demo for more explanation](https://regex101.com/r/Rw8Vyn/1)