# Replace chars up to a specific char using Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string "000-2.50" or "00-12.50" or "0-120.50" and I want to replace the zeros up to the minus sign "-" with an @ char.

I want to end up with "@@@-2.50" or "@@-12.50" or "@-120.50". How do I achieve that using Regex?

Comment: regex by itself doesnt replace at all. which language you are working with?

Comment: Tell us what language/tool you are using, and also do the zeroes to be replaced always start at the beginning of the string?

Comment: Tell us what language/tool you are using, and also do the zeroes to be replaced always start at the beginning of the string?

Comment: I am using JavaScript.  and also do the zeroes to be replaced always start at the beginning of the string? - YES

Answer (score 1):

Look for all zeros that are followed by a dash using a positive lookahead:

### Method 1:

```
0(?=[^-]*-)
```

JS Code:

```js
console.log(
  "000-2.50".replace(/0(?=[^-]*-)/g, "@")
);
```

### Method 2

Or if you only want leading zeros:

```js
console.log(
  "000-2.50".replace(/^0+(?=-)/g, function(match) {
      return "@".repeat(match.length);
  })
)
```

Comment: I'll give it a try, Thks Revo

Answer (score 0):

To replace each `0` from beginning of the string, how about using the [sticky flag `y`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4542304/what-does-regex-flag-y-do)

```js
var str = '000-2.50';

var res = str.replace(/0/gy, '@');

console.log(res);
```