# Regex: table line matcher

Tags: node.js, regex, markdown, cell

I want to parse a table line using regex.

Input

```
   |---|---|---|
|---|---|---|
```

So far I've come up with this regex:

```
/^(?<indent>\s*)\|(?<cell>-+|)/g
```

Regex101 Link: https://regex101.com/r/wzMYxd/1

But this regex is incomplete.

This only finds the first cell `--|`, but I want to find all the following cells as different `----|`.

Question: Can we catch the following cells with the same pattern using the regex?
ExpectedOutput: groups with array of matched cells: ["---|", "----|", "---|"]

Note: no constant number of `-` is required

Comment: How about [`^(?<indent>\h*)|\G\|(?<cell>-+)`](https://regex101.com/r/4woKJ7/1) what tool/lang are you using?

Comment: Woah, amazing. It's working as expected. Let me try some more cases. I'm using nodejs for parsing.

Comment: I doubt that works in JS, maybe enough to use [`\|(?<cell>-+)|^(?<indent>[\t ]*)`](https://regex101.com/r/Cd9EtU/1)

Comment: true, 1st one does not work with js :(

Comment: Is this processing line-wise or a multilinestring? Is it important that the matches are chained to each other? (the second pattern does not chain the matches (no `\G`). In JS there is the *sticky* `y` flag for chaining matches from start but makes only sense if single line input.

Comment: 2nd regex is pretty much complete. can we also avoid lines like `|--| -- |---|`

Comment: but if I compare it with the preceding/following line cell count, I can catch if this is a table line or not. (I'm comparing line wise| single line at once)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246248/discussion-between-kiran-parajuli-and-bobble-bubble).

Comment: I added a second solution with just one regex in my answer (maybe works for you). It needs to be used with the `y` (sticky) flag. Happy coding then! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about first verifying, if the line matches the pattern:

```
^[ \t]*\|(?:-+\|)+$
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/ErjZX0/1) - If it matches, extract the stuff:

```
^(?<indent>[\t ]*)\||(?<cell>-+)\|
```

[Another demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/CuBEze/1) (explanation on the right side)

---

With just one regex maybe by use of [*sticky* flag `y`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4542304/what-does-regex-flag-y-do) and a [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for validation:

```
/^(?<indent>[ \t]*)\|(?=(?:-+\|)+$)|(?!^)(?<cell>-+)\|/gy
```

[One more demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/SJUIAM/1)

The lookahead checks once after the first `|` if the rest of the string matches the pattern. If this first match fails, due to the `y` flag (matches are "glued" to each other) the rest of the pattern fails too.

Comment: I've simplified the regex that you suggested as `/^\s*\|(?=(?:[^/|]+\|)+$)|(?!^)(?<cell>[^|]+)\|/gy` to catch table rows like:
`| cell content | cell content |`. See: https://regex101.com/r/5G3qP5/1. But while using the sticky flag, I cannot use `/` char inside the cell content.
The above regex does not match text like: `|---|---| <here/> |`. Can you please suggest me what is going on?

Comment: @KiranParajuli Because you put the `/` into a [negated class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `[^/|]` [just remove the `/` from it](https://regex101.com/r/6Torke/1).

Comment: OMG, I was thinking I'm escaping the character `|`. But it was messing the regex up. Thank you @bobblebubble! You're great

Comment: YW @KiranParajuli :) The good thing about character classes is that you don't need much escaping of the characters inside. Just eg hyphen for matching literal `-` if it's not at start or end of the class (between chars it indicates a range inside a char class) or brackets  (not even necessarily but it's a good practice). Also the escape character is a backslash.